# Process of c++ executable doesn't close correctly

Tags: c++, process

in my program I start other c++ application in the same window closing the previous. Sometimes the process that I see in the Task Manager doesn't close. So I'll have many process whit the same name. How can I avoid this?

```html
startup("../folder/c++_executable.exe");
exit(0);
```

```html
void startup(LPCTSTR lpApplicationName)
{
   // additional information
   STARTUPINFO si;
   PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

   // set the size of the structures
   ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
   si.cb = sizeof(si);
   ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

  // start the program up
  CreateProcess( lpApplicationName,   // the path
    "",             // Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ;
    // Close process and thread handles.
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to check why it's not closing - get VisualStudio/WinDBG and attach to process that is not closing and check where it hang.

Comment: Codeblock also can attach to process: [link](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/attaching-to-a-running-process-using-codeblocks.html)